# Obtener valor de JSON en PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json

Estoy teniendo problemas para acceder a un valor especifico de una variable que retorna un JSON en PHP.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
//Llama el SP    
$sql="CALL tramites_G(".$valuesInsert.")";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($database,$sql);
           if (!$resultado) {
               die('error');
           } else {
            $jsondata["data"]["tramites"] = array();
            while($row = $resultado->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
                $jsondata["data"]["tramites"][0] = $row;
            }
            $code = json_encode($jsondata);
            }

    $var = json_decode($code,true);
```

Al hacer echo en `$jsondata` obtengo lo siguiente:

```
Array ( [data] => Array ( [tramites] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [vtr_id] => 122 ) ) ) )
```

Al hacer echo en `$code` obtengo lo siguiente:

```
{"data":{"tramites":[{"vtr_id":"122"}]}}
```

Necesito acceder al puro valor de `vtr_id` para asignarlo a una variable y seguir con una serie de validaciones.

Ya intente acceder con `$code[0]` pero no me devuelve valor alguno. También con `$id= $var->vtr_id;` pero sigue sin funcionar.

Answer (score 3):

puedes acceder ha ese valor en esta parte

```
while($row = $resultado->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $row["vtr_id"];// la puedes colocar en una variable o en un array con ayuda de array_push() 
    $jsondata["data"]["tramites"][0] = $row;
}
```

o puedes por su direccion en `$code` asi `$code["data"]["tramites"][0]["vtr_id"]`

Comment: Gracias, termine solucionandolo de otra manera:

<pre><code>while($row = $resultado->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
                $jsondata["data"]["tramites"][0] = $row;
                $code = $row['vtr_id'];
            }</code></pre>

Answer (score 1):

Ya obtuve el valor, muchas gracias por sus respuestas.

Adjunto los cambios que hice al código.

```
$sql="CALL tramites_G(".$valuesInsert.")";
$resultado = mysqli_query($database,$sql);
       if (!$resultado) {
           die('error');
       } else {
        $jsondata["data"]["tramites"] = array();
        while($row = $resultado->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
            $jsondata["data"]["tramites"][0] = $row;
            //Obtengo directamente el valor en el while
            $code = $row['vtr_id'];
        }
        }
```